# SQL Teradata Error 3704 with simple SELECT/FROM/WHERE statement - can't find the error

Tags: sql, teradata

Below is the question and my attempted answer, and I attached a picture of the schema. I'm not used to teradata and having a lot of trouble with it. Not sure if my SQL is just rusty, or if that program runs differently than those that I'm used to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Q: Find the average unit retail amount for electronic items purchased by Advantage members at Store 20 in Jan, 2000. Hint: Advantage Members are indicated by member_type 'V'. Category 5 is Electronics. For dates use the format ‘20000220’ for Feb 20, 2000

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpxI4.png)

```
SELECT AVG(Unit_Retail_Amount)

FROM item_scan, store_visits, member_index, item_desc

WHERE item_scan.visit_number = store_visits.visit_number 
AND store_visits.membership_nbr = member_index.membership_nbr 
AND item_scan.item_nbr = item_desc.item_nbr 
AND member_index.member_type = ‘V’ 
AND item_scan.transaction_date = ‘200001%’ 
AND item_desc.category_nbr = ‘5’;
```

Comment: Your single quotes look funky, like curly quotes, e.g. `‘200001%’` ... try using `'200001%'` instead.  Maybe this happened when you copied something over.  I have seen this happen with certain Mac OS text editors.

Comment: I noticed the same thing @TimBiegeleisen. Also tends to happen in anything with smart quotes like MSWord. You will find that both the open and close quotes are not valid for teradata, unless its just your post here that is *funky*.

Comment: Thank you for the advice; I never would have thought of that. However, I changed it and it still doesn't work although I am getting a new error code: 3807.

Comment: 3807 is an *object doesn't exist* error and will show the wrong name. You should use explicit join syntax `table JOIN table ON...`. And if `transaction_date` is actually stored as a CHAR (which is quite wrong) you need to apply `LIKE`: `item_scan.transaction_date LIKE ‘200001%’`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the others commenting on here that the explicit join syntax is better, and a LIKE statement should be used with wildcards rather than "=".  The 3807 error is likely caused by your where statement where you use "visit_number" when you should be using "visit_nbr" which is in your schema.